# Background Image width to 75% of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [image: this image]

As a background to a section on my page. I'd ideally like the white to stop at 75% of the screen (This will cover the content in the left grid).

Is this possible to do? I've just tried the following CSS :

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/page-bg.jpg") repeat-y scroll left center / auto 75%;
```

But had no such luck.

Can this be achieved. I'm using the Bootstrap 3 grid and have columns :

**lg-9** (Content) & **lg-3** (Right side navigation menu)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are applying 75% on height. Just use `75% auto` instead of `auto 75%`

```
background: #000  url("../img/page-bg.jpg") repeat-y left center;
background-size: 75% auto;
```

```css
div {
  width:300px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  background: #000 url(https://dummyimage.com/300x300/cccccc/ff0000.png&text=Sample-Text) repeat-y left center;
  background-size: 75% auto;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. It now appears to be ignoring the repeat property.

Screenshot : http://imgur.com/IqPXvYE

Comment: you can split it to two different property. check updated answer